# Jenkins job unable to clone from github

Tags: git, maven, github, jenkins

I am stuck at following message in the console:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Users\myusername\.jenkins\jobs\game-of-life\workspace
Checkout:workspace / C:\Users\myusername\.jenkins\jobs\game-of-life\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@5f06425e
Using strategy: Default
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@github.com:myusername/game-of-life.git
git --version
git version 1.8.4.msysgit.0
```

I have added git to PATH. 
Under Jenkins i have added JDK and Maven Home Directories and added Path to Git executable as:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe
```

Under Jenkins job configuration for SCM i added Git repo:

> git@github.com:myusername/game-of-life.git

I have also keys to Github and validated:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi myusername! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access
```

Under Jenkins URL i have:

```
http://localhost:8080/jenkins/
```

I am not sure what i am missing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how did you set up Jenkins on your machine, but by default, the Jenkins Windows installer sets up Jenkins to run as a service on Windows, which runs as the "Local System account", NOT your user account. Since the "Local System account" does not have SSH keys or known_hosts set up, “git clone” will hang during the build. Look at [Configuring Jenkins to use OpenSSH bundled with msysgit Windows installer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-)

Comment: I am not using it as a Windows service. I have deployed jenkins.war in tomcat

Comment: Technically it is the same problem. Most likely you run Tomcat with NOT your user account.

Comment: ok i could not get it to work with deploying to tomcat but was able to get it work with java -jar jenkins.war which deploys with jetty!